# Applying css to lightning-datatable header columns

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have created a Lightning Web Component which has a lightning-datatable.
I want to wrap the header row label.

At present, it is like this

[image]

I would like to display it like this

[image]

I have tried different options in the css file but nothing seems to work.
(Please note that the columns already have wrapText: true)

Update - As the header is shadow dom so we can accomplish this using css through static resource
Create a css file sponsorSalesStyles.css which contains style like this

```
.slds-table .slds-truncate {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: pre-wrap
}
```

Create a static resource using this css.

Then in your javascript controller import this static resource

```
import sponsorSalesStyles from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/sponsorSalesStyles';

import { loadStyle } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
connectedCallback() {
    Promise.all([
        loadStyle(this, sponsorSalesStyles)
    ])
    .catch(error => {
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error loading 1',
                message: error,
                variant: 'error'
            })
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/316790/edit) your question to add a list of the various things you tried in the CSS.

Comment: The static resource CSS approach - did you create a custom lightning datatable specialization, or is this in the parent component that includes the datatable in its template? Please edit the "answer" part of the question to clarify (then move this into an answer if the question gets re-opened).

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, since the header is generated by the component itself, and therefore contained in the lightning datatable component's shadow DOM, any CSS you create won't have any impact.

Even extending the lightning datatable component to create your own specialization and adding CSS in there won't work because the header is itself a nested component called the lightning-primitive-header-factory (you can see this in the DOM by using the browser's inspector).

An attempt to include HTML (such as a <br />) in the text won't work since the component will render this as text, not HTML.

Essentially what you want to do cannot be done until Salesforce provides this ability or you create your own version of the datatable.

Comment: But shouldn't the `wrapText` attribute added in [Spring '20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_lwc_components.htm) work as it was added specifically for lightning data table?

Comment: That apparently does not apply to the header, only the data rows...

Comment: Thanks @PhilW. Yes you are right,
There is a way to accomplish this though - its applying css through static resource.

Comment: @user2790625 if you managed to do this, please post an answer detailing how.

Comment: This question was closed so I could not add an answer. I have edited my question and added the solution

Comment: Given the edit I have voted to re-open the question so you can correctly post an answer.